# Update ListView entries value to another string-array in strings.xml

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a ListView in main.xml where android:entries="@array/list1" and I'd like to update that entries field to (say) @array/list2 by an onclick function.  Is this possible without an adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am almost certain that you must use an Adapter if you want to do it from java instead of xml.

[Here is a good example](http://www.mubasheralam.com/tutorials/android/listview-using-string-array-resources) of setting up an Adapter to do this.

I have never personally seen a way to do it without using an Adapter. I suspect that if a way to do this did exist it would be mentioned in the "related methods" section of the [docs for android:entries](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#attr_android%3aentries)